# asp-page-handler helper tag not populating the correct hyperlink

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with asp-page-handler populating the correct link when passing in an route value for an ID and not the handler (so "{int:id}" vs "{handler?}"). (See bottom of image).
I'm expecting something such as:
`https://localhost:5001/Emp/Download?id=Matthew.pdf`

[image: link at bottom shows current page link when hovering over Download and View]

In my small test app I hardcoded the employee id value into the `GetDirectoryReference("E000002/stubs/")` and it works fine. (Note that the E000002 is the value that changes dependant upon the logged in person. The value does populate in my OnGetAsync() call so no issue there).

Setup for customer interface GetEmployeePayrollNo:

```
public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeePayrollNo(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Employees
                .Include(e => e.EmployeePayroll)
                .Where(p => p.EmployeeId == id)
                .FirstAsync();

        }
```

In this test I'm trying to pass a variable into GetDirectoryReference dependant upon who is logged in.

Not sure what I'm messing up since selecting download or view doesn't even hit on debug mode.

Using Azure File Share to hold documents*
Using Razor pages for folder structure*

- Pages
- > Emp
- > Paystubs.cshtml

**Paystubs.cshtml takes an id route value for the person logged in. In my test application it took a "{handler?}" route value. Not sure if I can use both???**

Model

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ICustomer _customer;

        public PaystubsModel(IConfiguration configuration,
            ICustomer customer)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _customer = customer;
        }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public List<AzureFileModel> AzureFileModel { get; private set; } = new List<AzureFileModel>();
        public async Task OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            Employee = await _customer.GetEmployeePayrollNo(id);
            var empPayNo = Employee.EmployeePayroll;

            string fileStorageConnection = _configuration.GetValue<string>("FileStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(fileStorageConnection);
            CloudFileShare share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("test");
            CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference(empPayNo.EmployeeOnline+"/stubs");

            // list all files in the directory
            AzureFileModel = await ListSubDir(dir);
        }

public static async Task<List<AzureFileModel>> ListSubDir(CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory)
{
// LEFT OUT FOR BREVITY
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDownload(string fileId)
        {
            var empPayNo = Employee.EmployeePayroll;

            string fileStorageConnection = _configuration.GetValue<string>("FileStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(fileStorageConnection);
            CloudFileShare share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("test");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFileDirectory dir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(empPayNo.EmployeeOnline+"/stubs");
            CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference(fileId);

            if (!file.Exists())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "File not found.");
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(new MemoryStream());
                Stream fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                return File(fileStream, file.Properties.ContentType, file.Name);
            }

        }
```

Page:

```
@page "{id:int}"   //*******In my test model I was using {handler?} but I need to pass in the employee id to route here to display only the logged in employee. Again, not sure if its possible to use both?

@model NavraePortal.WebApp.Pages.Emp.PaystubsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Documents";
}

<h1>Pay Stub Copies</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>File Date</th>
            <th>Download</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var data in Model.AzureFileModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@data.FileName</td>
                <td>@data.DateModified</td>
                <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@data.FileName" asp-page-handler="Download">Download</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" asp-route-id="@data.FileName" asp-page-handler="View">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this `id` in `asp-route-id` is not matched with the `fileId`. In this page, you need to modify it.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-fileId="@data.FileName" asp-page-handler="Download">Download</a>
```

Then, this url is updated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured that out later in the night. That's what I get for copying and pasting from my test project to this one. I am however having issues getting the value of `empPayNo.EmployeeOnline` to populate in my `OnGetDownload.GetDirectoryReference(empPayNo.EmployeeOnline+"/stubs/")` method. It returns null. I thought since I set it to Employee property that the property would hold the value. Guess not!